# Saving printed documents in a Windows Server machine

Tags: printing, windows-server-2003

Do you know any way to have a copy of all documents printed through print queues of a Windows Server 2003 machine? I'd like to audit what people is printing.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set the queue to keep printed documents.

EDIT:
If you want to 'move them' to another place then you will probably have to put some kind of different port monitor in place.  You could use something like [Redmon](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/) (or we have a Commercial product) that would write the data to file, and then route it to the actual printer.

There are other server based tools that could allow for this along with other tracking capabilities.

Comment: Any way to keep documents out of print queu folder? I'd like not to show printed documents inside pinter dialog queue.